# JavaScript: How to JSON.Stringify Date object without ISO Date Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm sending the following JSON as part of an Ajax request, where Param #1 is a Date string.

```
data : JSON.stringify({'localCreatedDate' : new Date(), 
                       'localUserAgent' : navigator.userAgent
                       )});
```

**However, the date I need is the original literal JS string which looks like:**

`Sun Sep 08 2019 17:33:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

But `JSON.stringify()` is making it:

`2019-09-08T21:33:32.016Z`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than send the `Date` object directly, you could call [`Date#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) to ensure that `localCreatedDate` is sent to the server as a string, in the required format:

```
data : JSON.stringify({
    'localCreatedDate' : new Date().toString(), 
    'localUserAgent' : navigator.userAgent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using `JSON.stringify` automatically calls the `.toJSON` method of the `Date` object. What you should do to get your desired result is to cast the `Date` object to a string or just call the `.toString` method on the date object

`String`

```
data : JSON.stringify({
            'localCreatedDate' : String(new Date()), 
            'localUserAgent' : navigator.userAgent
       )});
```

`toString`

```
data : JSON.stringify({
            'localCreatedDate' : (new Date()).toString(), 
            'localUserAgent' : navigator.userAgent
       )});
```